# jQuery Slider Gallery (slider with Scrollbar) stopped working after Update to jQuery 1.5

Tags: jquery

I love the Slider Gallery on http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slider-gallery/, but unfortunately it stopped working after I updated jquery + jqueryUI. Any Ideas, how to improve the code [Or an similar Tutorial/Script], to get it back to work? The javascript looks like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
        var container = $('div.sliderGallery');
        var ul = $('ul', container);

        var itemsWidth = ul.innerWidth() - container.outerWidth();

        $('.slider', container).slider({
            min: 0,
            max: itemsWidth,
            handle: '.handle',
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                ul.animate({'left' : ui.value * -1}, 500);
            },
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                ul.css('left', ui.value * -1);
            }
        });
    };
```

The HTML/CSS is pretty simple; An Container (the div.SliderGallery) with hidden Overflow and 100% width, an ul with the Content inside and the Scrollbar in a div. Works fine with an old jQuery-Version (1.3 or something), but doesn't do anything with V1.5.

Thank you very much,

Best regards

Lucas

Comment: is there a reason why you need to upgrade jquery and jquery ui? If not you should simply got back to the version that worked

Comment: unfortunately I use a couple of other functions [especially a selfmade accordion-like Menustructure], which won't work with the older jQuery Version. It seems to be the jQuery, not the jQuery UI, if that helps to solve the problem...

Comment: found another nice example for what I'm looking for: http://www.celeuma.pt. It seems to be Wordpress, but they use a slider like i want to build. Unfortunately I can't figure wich part of the slider.js is doing the trick... maybe someone of you guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem with the exact same problem - The newest version of jQuery is called on the master asp.net page, and I needed to include jQuery 1.2.6 in a page with the slider...There's lots of posts on here about using the noConflict(); argument w/ this exact same code. Anyways, here's what I did:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery.nyroModal.js"></script>//This was my conflicting code - lightboxes weren't working any more with the slider implemented
<script src="includes/js/slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>//This is jQuery 1.2.6 that I renamed for organizational purposes
<script src="includes/js/jquery-ui-full-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>//Here's the UI that the slider requires
<script type="text/javascript">
var jqSlider = $.noConflict(true);//You MUST use the noConflict method directly after loading the preferred library
    jqSlider(function(){ // Replace all $ as follows
        var container = jqSlider('div.sliderGallery');
        var ul = jqSlider('ul', container);
        var itemsWidth = ul.innerWidth() - container.outerWidth();
        jqSlider('.slider', container).slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 5800,
            handle: '.handle',
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                ul.animate({'left' : ui.value * -1}, 500, 'linear');
            },
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                ul.css('left', ui.value * -1);
            }
        });
    });
</script>// After this the rest of my functions follow, using the normal $ and jQuery 1.5
```

Works for me now - the tricky part is just arranging the script calls and your function correctly. Hope this helps.

Comment: woah finally someone's here to help me out! :-) It was driving me insane... One (maybe^^) final Question: I include the code like you told me and put my <script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery-1.5.js" charset="utf-8"></script> and <script type='text/javascript' src="js/funktionen.js" charset="utf-8"></script> (where my other jQuery-Stuff is written in) afterwards, right?

Comment: It shouldn't matter as long as the noConflict argument is written in the correct spot, but my pages have the latest jQuery library and my other plugins ABOVE my older jQuery and slider. I also have a few functions (not script calls) below it, which work fine.

Comment: Hm, I'm pretty close (I'm feeling it^^), but still not there. When I implement all the stuff it seems all fine (no error, the functions wich require jQuery 1.5 are working), but as soon as I implement the slider-function (as you pointed out above), the jQuery-Functions in function.js stop working. :-( The Implement-Order looks like this (with the right syntax of course): <jQuery-1.5> - <jQuery-PNGfix> - <functions.js> - <jQuery-1.2.6> - <jQueryUI-1.5.2> - <SliderCode like you use it above> Any Ideas??

Comment: Arghl. It was a typo. More than 24Hours straight coding DO decrease your concentration. Thanks a lot Collin, you're my hero.

Comment: Sorry, one last question; var itemsWidth = ul.innerWidth() - container.outerWidth(); doesn't work anymore, cause both have the value 0. Any Idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Grmpf invisible Elements of course have width:0. There seems to be a workaround though: http://devblog.foliotek.com/2009/12/07/getting-the-width-of-a-hidden-element-with-jquery-using-width/ ... I really need some sleep... Thanks again, i'm out and unplugged...

Comment: Happy to help - I set a max width on my scroller in order to plug in some other controller functions to it. If you're hiding the elements, you could always use the CSS visibility: hidden; property to keep it in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

though collins solution worked fine, I was still searching for another way in order to use only one library in the final document. Finally I figured out a Solution which works fine with jQuery5 and UI1.8.9 and of course I'm happy to share it to anyone who has use for it:

The HTML-Markup:

```
<div id="gallery">
   <div id="content">Content to slide goes here</div>
</div>

<div id="scrollbar">
   <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.gallery {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;}

 .content {
    position: relative;
    overflow: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;}

.ui-slider {position: relative; width:464px; margin-left:40px;}  
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
        margin-top:2px;
        background-color: #999; 
        position: absolute; 
        width:80px; 
        height:8px; 
        left:0px;}  

.scrollBar {
        position: relative; 
        background-color: #CCC; 
        width:544px; 
        height:12px; 
        margin-left:53px;
        }   

.ui-slider-horizontal {}
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {margin-left: -40px;} 
.container a:active, .container a:visited, .container a:focus {top:0; left:0;}
```

And finally the important part, the jQuery-Stuff:

```
var maxScroll = 2605 - $("body").width();
var scrollable = $("#content");
$("#slider").slider({
    max: maxScroll,
    slide: function (e, ui) {
        scrollable.css("left", "-" + ui.value + "px")
    }
});
```

the 2605 is the width of the #content-div. Maybe this helps anybody else...