# How to refresh single Javascript Function when window.resize is called

Tags: jquery, refresh, slider

I'm stucked once again;

I've got a jQuery-Function in the Tag of a php-File, which gets the Screenwidth for a Gallery. It's called when the page loads and works pretty well. But now I want the function to be called again, everytime the window is resized in order to get the new Screenwidth right. One possibility is to use window.location.href to reload the whole page when window.resize is called, but that's not what I want.

Is there a way to only reload the function (or the entire javascript Code Block written in the ) without reloading linked js-files and the html-Structure?? I just want to reload this single function:

```
jqSlider(function(){

                var container = jqSlider('div.sliderGallery'); 
                var ul = jqSlider('ul', container); 
                var fensterBreite = jqSlider("#preloader").outerWidth(); 
                var itemsWidth = 2559 - fensterBreite; 

            jqSlider('.slider', container).slider({
                min: 0,
                max: itemsWidth,
                handle: '.handle',
                stop: function (event, ui) {
                    ul.animate({'left' : ui.value * -1}, 500, 'linear');
                },
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    ul.css('left', ui.value * -1);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I admit I'm a bit confused by your syntax and I apologize if I'm not spot on here so let me know if this isn't what you needed and I'll do my best to modify the code to meet your needs.  You appear to be passing an anonymous function to the method jqSlider, so working on that assumption:

1. Move your anonymous function to a stored memory location
2. Pass the function reference to your jqSlider method
3. Bind the function reference to the window's resize event

```
var mySliderFunc = function () {

    var container = jqSlider('div.sliderGallery');
    var ul = jqSlider('ul', container);
    var fensterBreite = jqSlider("#preloader").outerWidth();
    var itemsWidth = 2559 - fensterBreite;

    jqSlider('.slider', container).slider({
        min: 0,
        max: itemsWidth,
        handle: '.handle',
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            ul.animate({ 'left': ui.value * -1 }, 500, 'linear');
        },
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            ul.css('left', ui.value * -1);
        } 
    });
};

jqSlider(mySliderFunc);

$(window).resize(mySliderFunc);
```

Comment: If the .slider() method takes "destroy" as an argument to invoke a destructor call, you may want to add a line to destroy the slider before reinitializing it. Otherwise, you may experience strange behavior on trying to reinitialize the method on a DOM element already containing a slider.

Comment: Ah sorry for the weird syntax, I use two different jQuery-Versions in one Document, therefor I used var jqSlider = $.noConflict(true) which causes the weird code. Anyway, I tried your advice, but something weird happens: The function is called, even if it's moved to a stored memory location and I'm not calling it. That's not really a problem of course, but when I destroy the slider and try to reinitializing it, it's destroyed without reinitializing. I tried jqSlider(window).resize(function() {jqSlider('.slider', container).slider("destroy"); mySliderFunc();}) Ideas??

Comment: Is #preloader still in the DOM and visible when the resize function is called?

Comment: in fact it wasn't, but even if i change #preloader to body (which is always visible), it won't do the trick. If I use mySliderFunc() there is a error, that mySliderFunc is not a function, but when i use mySliderFunc without the braces the error is gone, but it still just kills the slider without creating a new one. Maybe the destroy and the new Slider somehow collide and should be called in a row somehow!?

Comment: I'm still hoping for help, cause even putting the functions (with a little help of a fade and a callback) in a row doesn't help. It still kills the Slider without setting a new one up...

Comment: finally I find a solution. I updated my slider [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881630/jquery-slider-gallery-slider-with-scrollbar-stopped-working-after-update-to-jqu], and now I found a solution to solve the refresh-Problem! Thanks lthibodeaux for your help, your idea was the solution! Instead of var mySliderFunc i use jQuery.fn.mySliderFunc, this gives me the possibility to call the function. Destroy AND setting a new one up (and reseting the slider) like this: $(window).resize(function() {$("#slider").slider("destroy"); $("#gallery").css("left", "0px"); jQuery.fn.mySliderFunc(); });